# Formatting a Second Page of Details

Tags: crystal-reports

This is a problem I've managed to come up with a semi-solution for in the past, but I thought someone else might know better.

I have a report in **Crystal Reports 10** that is used as an order summary form for a production area. We have standard products that only have one item per code, and then we have kits. A kit will have one primary item, and a secondary item, both of which need their own page in this summary as they go to different areas.

To accomplish this I've taken the normal details area from the report and made a copy of each section. This second set of details sections only shows when a record contains a kit, and they force a new page before them. To the average observer this makes it appear as though there are two separate items on the order, when in reality there is only one.

In my page header there is a flag that needs to show only on these secondary pages. My problem is that there is no special attribute for these second pages that sets them apart from the first page of a record. To make this formatting happen I've created a somewhat effective formula, but it doesn't work in all possible configurations.

The formula is:

```
(PageNumber = 2
or ({%kit count} = 1 and (PageNumber - 1) = RecordNumber)
or ({%kit count} > 1 and (PageNumber -2) = RecordNumber)) then false
```

`%kit count` is just a formula that gets a total count for kit codes in the report.

Currently this works only on a few specific cases. I'm sure there's some kind of pattern in the available values that I could work with, but I'm just not seeing it.

I need to be able to trigger this formula on every second page on a kit. How can I accomplish that?

EDIT: Screenshots as requested. (Brace yourselves)

[image: [Screenshot 1]]

(Original at http://cl.ly/392f033Y131e3r0l100V)

[image: [Screenshot 2]]

(Original at http://cl.ly/2x1D0t0W0S0j0F0h0S28)

Comment: Could you do a screenshot of the report in design mode? It sounds like you might be able to get what you're looking to achieve by removing the page header and placing the items in either a group or detail section.

Comment: @LeeTickett - Done. These summaries print based on an order number, and the details section is populated by each line item on the order. Normally every line item gets its own page, unless they're inconsequential codes like rush's, reverse collates, etc. Each page has to have everything from the top sections of the report, as those are used to guide the item through our workflow.

Comment: I haven't looked at the screenshots yet but you can set group headers to repeat on every page which makes them practically the same as page headers.

Comment: @LeeTickett - How exactly would that make it easier to identify and flag these secondary pages?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to fully understand what you're trying to do without a discussion. Here is the solution to what I think you want to do with some made up data:

```
OrderNo    Line    Kit    Rush
1          1       a      0
1          1       b      0
1          2       NULL   0
1          3       NULL   1
1          4       NULL   1
```

I create a group based on a formula (pretend OrderNo and Line are varchar so I don't have to cast :)

```
if {Rush} = 1 then
 {OrderNo} & '-Rush'
else if isnull({Kit}) then
 {OrderNo} & '-' & {Line}
else
 {OrderNo} & '-' & {Line} & '-' & {Kit}
```

Then in the group header I place all of the stuff you currently have in your page header and enable `Repeat Group Header on each Page.`

Then finally put my detail in.

Comment: I'll give this a shot first thing Monday morning. Thanks for your help.